# Determine when user has clicked inside datagrid but not on a row

Tags: wpf, datagrid

I am trying to write a simple method like below that makes a condition true if a user has clicked on the datagrid but not on a row.

I can only find information on how to do this with a datagridview, but the wpf datagrid doesn't seem to have the same functionality.

```
    private void dataGrid_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        Point where = new Point();
        var ht = dataGrid.InputHitTest(where);

        if (ht.)
        {
            //clicked on grey area
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<DataGrid UIElement.PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown="DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown" ... >
```

Code :

```
private void DataGrid_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(e.OriginalSource.ToString());
        DependencyObject parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent((Visual)e.OriginalSource);
        while (parent as DataGrid == null && parent as DataGridRow == null)
        { 
            parent = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(parent);
        }
        if (parent as DataGrid != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked inside DataGrid");
        else if (parent as DataGridRow != null)
            MessageBox.Show("Clicked inside DataGridRow");
    }
```